# Why are static and dynamic imports in node.js treated differently wrt read-only?

Tags: node.js, node-modules, es6-modules

Why would node.js 15.4.0 treat static and dynamic imports differently wrt to their read-only behavior?

I have a file test.mjs which reads

```
let a = {x: 1};
export default a;
```

When i use this in a dynamic import:

```
async function run () {
  var m = await import ("./test.mjs");
  m.d=45;
  console.log (m);
}
run();
```

it complains that the object is not extensible (and this conforms to my reading of the standard that imports provide read-only bindings).

However, when I use this statically as in

```
import m from './test.mjs';
m.d = 44;
console.log (m);
```

this works nicely and outputs `{x:1, d:44}`.

Why does this work? Is this not in violation of the standard?

The question is of particular importance for a design decision to be taken now and I am afraid eventually node would also treat static imports as read-only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The same assignment works for the dynamic import:

```
(async function() {
  const { default: m } = await import("./test.mjs");
//      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  m.d = 45;
  console.log(m);
})();
```

You need to add the property to the default-exported object, not to the immutable namespace.

You'd get the same error when using a static namespace import:

```
import * as m from './test.mjs';
m.d = 44;
//  ^ ReferenceError
```