# "object is not extensible" while accessed via `import()` function

Tags: javascript, import, module

I'm importing my JavaScript "module" using the "[dynamic `import()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import)" call:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"><title>Module</title><style>:root { background: #545454; }</style>
  <script>
    window.addEventListener('load', e => {
      import('./script.js').then(async module => {
        const fn = await module.myFunction();
        fn.whatever();
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body></body></html>
```

and, this is the `script.js` file:

```
export async function myFunction() {
    this.whatever = function () {
        console.log('Ok');
    };
    return this;
}
```

By running it, Google Chrome complains that the "`object is not extensible`" while adding `whatever`:

> ```
> script.js:2 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot add property whatever, object is not extensible
>     at Module.myFunction (script.js:2:19)
>     at module.html:12:33
> ```

So, what's wrong and how to work around the issue?

Comment: What are you trying to do with `this.whatever = ___` in `myFunction`? It's odd to use `this` on a top-level exported function, much less to modify the object `this` may be pointing at.

Comment: (There's also no reason to mark a function `async` if the function doesn't use `await`.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thank you for your quick and elaborate responses, I do appreciate it, actually the real counterpart of the `myFunction` is kind of an "entry point", starting other modules and doing other stuff. I've put the `async` there to present a perfect mock-up of my situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`module` in the `then` callback on that `import()` is the *module namespace object* for the module. That's an object the JavaScript engine creates that has properties for the exports of the module. The MNO is not extensible; its purpose is to accurately reflect the exports of the module. If you could add properites to it (extend it), it wouldn't accurately reflect the module exports anymore.

When you call `module.myFunction()`, `this` during the call is set to `module` during the call — which is the non-extensible module namespace object. So the line `this.whatever = ___` in `myFunction` fails, because that's trying to create a new property on a non-extensible object.

---

Just as an addition: It's not clear what you're trying to do with `myFunction`, but you *could* create a new object that uses the MNO as its prototype, and add a property to that.

```
// (Side note: `async` only makes sense on functions that use `await`. Perhaps
// you're using `await` in code that wasn't relevant to the question in which
// case that makes sense, but I thought I should flag it up in not and for
// others reading the code.)
export async function myFunction() {
    const obj = Object.create(this);
    obj.whatever = function () {
        console.log("Ok");
    };
    return obj;
}
```

I'd suggest caution doing that with code you don't control just because A) it's using module exports as prototype methods which may have unintended consequences, and B) there may be a simpler, more well-supported way to do it with any given specific module. But it should work in most cases.

Comment: This is simply amazing, confirming on your recommendation, it would be just irrelevant to have the MNO as the "base object"; but it only makes sense after you've ingeniously clarified the cause (which the documentation failed to elaborate on); thank you so much, I truly appreciate it :)

Comment: @T.J. I dynamically import the library `three.js` and then dynamically import a third-party geometry library that extends the `THREE` namespace. I get the same error as stated in the OP's title using dynamic import but no error when the libraries are loaded through `<script type="module" src="./path"></script>`. Your reference to the use of `Object.create` in the `then` callback of `import()` fixes the error: E.g. `THREE = Object.create(threeModule);`. Your MNO explanation clarifies what's happening. Can you expand on your comment "I wouldn't recommend doing that without a good reason"?

Comment: @DaveB - I'm glad that helped! I've reworded the bit at the end to explain why this sets off my "this is going to bite me" spidey-sense. :-)

Comment: These posts are related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74761074/how-to-extend-a-dynamically-imported-module and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65379477/why-are-static-and-dynamic-imports-in-node-js-treated-differently-wrt-read-only