# How to extend a dynamically imported module?

Tags: javascript, node.js, d3.js

I'm trying to update a library to dynamically import `d3.js` after the upgrade to v7, and this syntax handles the import:

```js
import("d3").then((library) => {
    var d3 = library;
    console.log("d3:", d3);
})
.catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
});
```

The logged object is in this format (albeit much longer):

[image: Logged "Module" type]

Whenever I try to simply extend by adding a property with `d3.contextMenu = factory(d3);`, I get this `TypeError`:

```
TypeError: Cannot add property contextMenu, object is not extensible
```

Doing a shallow clone like `var d3 = {...library, contextMenu: factory(library)};` removes a lot of the module's context, e.x. the `get` and `set` methods are not copied at all.

So I tried to create a structured clone of the library before extending it with `var d3 = structuredClone(library);`, but that gives a `DOMExteption`:

```
DOMException: Failed to execute 'structuredClone' on 'Window': [object Module] could not be cloned.
```

When using the non-ESM syntax, this code covers all my bases and allows for extension of the module:

```js
if (typeof module === "object" && module.exports) {
    var d3 = require("d3");
    module.exports = factory(d3);
} else if (typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
    try {
        var d3 = require("d3");
    } catch (e) {
        d3 = root.d3;
    }

    d3.contextMenu = factory(d3);
    define([], function () {
        return d3.contextMenu;
    });
} else if (root?.d3) {
    root.d3.contextMenu = factory(root.d3);
}
```

But I need to add in ESM compatibility for the library, hence my code. What method can I use to extend the module with my function?

Comment: Here's a [GitHub link](https://github.com/TargetPackage/d3-context-menu/blob/master/js/d3-context-menu.js#L1) to the definition, I'm not familiar with the name of this pattern to describe it to you; it's basically the return value of an immediately invoked function, but I don't think it's IIFE.

Comment: Do you have a code example of an issue caused by your rejected `var d3 = { ...library, contextMenu: factory(library) };`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is not possible to extend an inextensible object, you can either wrap the library or use it as the prototype of a new object. For example:

```js
import('d3').then((library) => {
  const d3 = Object.create(library);
  d3.contextMenu = factory(library);
  for (const prop in d3) console.log(prop);
})
.catch((err) => {
    console.error(err);
});
```

To export:

```js
module.exports = (async () => {
  const library = await import('d3');
  const d3 = Object.create(library);
  d3.contextMenu = factory(library);
  return d3;
})();
```

To then import into CommonJS module using `require`:

```js
(async () => {
  const d3 = await require('./filename.js');
  for (const prop in d3) console.log(prop);
})();
```

Comment: Seems like it works to me, thanks! Any chance you know how I can export the new `d3` object after making that modification? Since it's not top-level I don't know of a way to do it dynamically with the ES6 syntax.

Comment: @AaronMeese Added export example.